# Dynamic accounts in anchor

Tags: anchor, solana-program

Is there a way to have accounts.

Suppose I want the signer to change the `Signer` for my transaction depending on whether a PDA is initialized. Can I do this in the `Accounts` struct

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
  #[account(mut)]
  pub my_signer: Signer<'info>,
  #[account(mut)]
  pub admin_signer: Signer<'info>,
  #[account(
      init, // initialize if signer is admin_signer
      payer = signer,
      seeds = [b"my_pda_seed".as_ref()], 
      bump,
  )]
  pub pda: AccountInfo<'info, PDA>, // Program Derived Address account
  #[system_program] 
  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

I want to change between `admin_signer` and `my_signer` depending on whether the `pda` account is initialized.

Is there a way to do this on the `Accounts` struct.

My current option is using optional accounts and checking whether the pda is initialized on the client side and passing in the appropriate account. But there is the initialization step and this will fail if I pass in `my_signer` with an already initialized account

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this through the anchor macros unfortunately, but you can create an issue on their repo to ask about adding this capability! It might be a bit tricky, but that's for them to figure out :-)